# PHP Executing Bash Script returning just black screenshots

Tags: php, linux, apache, bash, screenshot

You are probably familliar with the website thumbnail services out there like websnapr.com e.g.

I'm currently working on something like it with different purposes, so obivously I needed a server which would launch a webbrowser with an url take a screenshot and go to the next one.

This is the bash script that I execute by bash script.sh 'http://google.nl' /var/www/images/google.png

```
#! /bin/bash
export DISPLAY=":4"
killall firefox-bin
/usr/bin/firefox --display :4 "$1" &
/bin/sleep 20
xte "key F11"
/bin/sleep 3
/usr/bin/import -window root -display :4 "$2"
/bin/sleep 3
killall firefox-bin
```

and I have an Xvfb running by 'Xvfb :4 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &'

The script works fine while running via ssh or just the terminal on the standard user, but when I try to execute it through php like:

```
exec('bash /var/scripts/test.sh "http://google.nl" /var/www/char.png');
```

all I get is a fully black screenshot of 1024x768, when looking in apache's error logs I see that it can't killall firefox when I have it running under the main user (permission not permitted) but even when it's closed it can't start one (not giving an error).

Any idea what's wrong? Ideally since it works on my main user it would just want to be able to execute it as that user instead of www-data user, security isn't an issue since there will be no direct connection to that server (only via another server on the same network).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not surprising that an application running from Apache cannot access the X11 as nicely. I'd use [xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) + [xvfb-run](http://www-linux.gsi.de/cgi-bin/man2html?xvfb-run+1).

On the other hand, while playing with `xte` in extreme cases is fine, it's a bit hacky when you have clean solutions; try projects like [cutycapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) or similar.

Comment: problem is that i do need to render flash content, as far as i recall researching those is that they do not support that? (referring to cutycapt)

Comment: +1 for suggesting CutyCapt, I was about to recommend the same.

Comment: @M0rph3v5: try it and let us know. I can't see why the flash content shouldn't be rendered, though.

Comment: @M0rph3v5: if you add the "plugins" command-line option and install the Flash plugin correctly, it should even render those. You may have to tweak the "delay" parameter to get correct results.

Comment: I'll give it a try, also I've tried using xvfb-run but the screenshots rendered are still just fully black (due firefox not being ran).

Comment: Ok, with the plugins on and a small delay the flash renders perfectly. Gonna see what happens now when I try to execute it from php :)

Comment: It's working like expected, but the only problem I'm having now is that it somehow standardly renders the flash background as black (whilst it's supposed to be white).